# How to understand "Cassandra Messaging"

Tags: cassandra

I've read that Cassandra can be used for messaging: http://www.datastax.com/messaging

But it does not have push functionality, so I would have to pool for messages in my application. I tough that push functionality is obligatory for messaging systems.

Could some explain how to interpret term `messaging` in case of Cassandra?

Comment: Well, take a look at messaging example (use case) presented by [DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/DataStax-CS-ConstantContact.pdf): [ConstanContact](http://www.constantcontact.com/index.jsp) is a provider of email marketing application and this is what do they mean by "messaging" in that context. Cassandra in this case is just a database used by this "messaging" application so it has nothing to do with pushing/pulling messages. So I believe you confused different abstraction layers.

Comment: I would also suggest changing title of this question to something to show that this question regards Cassandra not messaging generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They says:

> Amplifying the issue is real-time communication and collaboration
>   between diverse user groups and applications. Legacy messaging
>   platforms are not designed to effectively address the challenges.

and then

> DataStax is optimized for continuous availability and disaster
>   recovery and makes the management of large scale messaging solutions
>   easy.

So this "messaging" mean messaging between users, like twits, chats, posts, emails and so on. It's not messaging between application like RabbitMQ

Comment: I was confused, because they have examples of chat application. In this case they have to denormalise data and periodically pool for new messages - is this correct?

Comment: It completely depends from the application. With Akka you can hold actor as a chat room and other actors as a users in that chat room and communicate by akka messages, so cassandra would be used only as a backup storage - to restore history after close\open chat room.